# One Cup in Grams

Tags: pancakes, measuring-scales

How much is a cup of milk in grams?

Of course I can search google and get it (240gr) but that sounds too much for making **pancakes** . I don't have a measuring cup and I have to use 1+1/4 cup milk and I don't know how! 240 sounds too much.

this is the recipe :

> 1.5 cup of floor, 1.25 cup of milk, 1 egg. the rests are not main ingredients.

Comment: Just curious why you're trying to convert a pancake recipe? There are loads of metric pancake recipes out there. FWIW, I've been making pancakes my whole life (both American and English style) and by far, the best, most foolproof recipe comes from this gem of a cookbook - Yeo Valley Great British Farmouse Cookbook: http://amzn.to/2uhA2LQ - It's also an incredibly solid and reliable cookbook - loved just about every single recipe.

Comment: It would also be interesting if you could [edit] your question to add the rest of the recipe you're using, so we can see the proportion between the ingredients

Comment: Very, very helpful chart for converting volumetric measurements to measurements by weight (or vice versa). Hundreds of ingredients - grams or ounces:  http://www.kingarthurflour.com/learn/ingredient-weight-chart.html  I use it *all the time.*

Comment: That sounds pretty close, since there are over 28 grams per ounce, and eight ounces per cup, but we're mixing weight and volume units (would come to 227 grams by weight.  1 & 1/4 cups = 10 ounces, so 283.5), a bit.

Comment: Sacrilege, but: pancakes tend to be be forgiving and I tend to adjust to my own liking as for and thick or thin anyway, I would use a drinking glass that I thought was about 12 ounces (1 1/2 cups) and fill it all the way with flour, then not quite full with milk and you have the right ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

One cup of milk weighs 245g. So 1+1/4 cup weighs 306.25g.

If the mixture turns out too runny, just add a bit more flour.

Comment: well the thing is that i gotta add one egg, 1+1/4 milk (cup) + 1+1/2 flour, isn't that funny? guess the ingredient is for 2 eggs and is actually twice the ingredient for one egg ! it's meant to become pancakes!

Comment: @parvin 1+1/2 *what* of flour? Cups? You know that would be about 150 grams (depending on your flour), right? By the way, I did a Google search for "pancake recipe" and looked at the very first hit. http://allrecipes.com/recipe/21014/good-old-fashioned-pancakes/ How 'bout that? Exactly 1 1/2 cups flour, 1 1/4 cups milk, and **1(!)** egg (plus 3 1/2 tsp baking powder, 1 tsp salt, 1 TBS sugar and 3 TBS butter)

Comment: is the egg enough for all those milk and floor? if so I have to change my recipe. thank you! :)

Comment: Yes, one egg should be enough. Pancakes don't really need many, they just need quite a bit of liquid. This is assuming you aren't making American pancakes (called crumpets in Britain) because in that case the ratios seem a bit off. If you are making normal, flat and thin pancakes then it seems fine to me.